# Hard drives not recognized on Windows 8 unless entering BIOS first

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8, bios, sata, device-manager

I've built a new computer.  My old computer had two SATA 3GB drives:

- [1TB Seagate Barracuda 7200.11 (ST31000340AS)](http://www.seagate.com/docs/pdf/datasheet/disc/ds_barracuda_7200_11.pdf)
- [750 GB Seagate Barracuda 7200.10 (ST3750640AS)](http://www.seagate.com/support/disc/manuals/sata/100402371a.pdf)

The new computer uses an [OCZ Vertex 4 SATA III 2.5" drive (SATA III/6 Gbps)](http://www.ocztechnology.com/ocz-vertex-4-sata-iii-2-5-ssd.html#overview) as the boot/main drive (C), the other drives are D and E (there are actually multiple partitions on one of the drives and it's merged through Disk Manager, but that doesn't seem to be indicative of the problem).

The motherboard is an [ASUS P9X79 Pro](http://www.asus.com/Motherboard/P9X79_PRO/).  The OCZ drive is connected to a 6GB port and the two Barracudas are attached to 3GB ports.

When I boot up the computer straight to Windows 8, the Barracuda drives don't appear in Windows Explorer:

[image: Windows Explorer without Barracuda drives showing]

Looking in Device Manager shows nothing out of the ordinary, except that the drives simply are not there:

[image: Device Manager without Barracuda drives showing]

If I restart the computer, or start the computer and go into the BIOS and go to Advanced/SATA Configuration, they appear in the BIOS:

[image: ASUS P9X79 Pro BIOS with drives showing]

If I exit and save the configuration (I'm prompted without changing anything, just going to advanced mode and looking at the SATA display):

[image: ASUS P9X79 BIOS prompt to save]

And then boot into Windows 8, the drives appear and function as if they were always there:

[image: Windows Explorer with Barracuda drives showing]

The drives work fine at that point.

The BIOS is set up to use AHCI SATA mode (as opposed to disabled, IDE, or RAID):

[image: AHCI SATA mode]

Although at one point, it was set to IDE, but the problem existed when set in that mode.

It's been pointed out that it could be a power issue.  My PSU is a [Silverstone Strider Plus ST50F-P 500W ATX 12V v2.3](http://www.silverstonetek.com/product.php?pid=274) modular power supply.  It's powering:

- The three drives mentioned above
- [G.SKILL Ripjaws X Series 16GB (2 x 8GB) 240-Pin DDR3 SDRAM 1600 (PC3 12800)](http://www.gskill.com/products.php?index=422)
- [Intel Core i7-3930K Sandy Bridge-E 3.2GHz (3.8GHz Turbo) LGA 2011 130W Six-Core Desktop Processor](http://ark.intel.com/products/63697/Intel-Core-i7-3930K-Processor-12M-Cache-up-to-3_80-GHz)
- [CORSAIR Hydro Series H80i Water Cooler](http://www.corsair.com/us/hydro-series-h80i-high-performance-liquid-cpu-cooler.html)

All of this is in an [Antec Three Hundred Two Black Steel ATX Mid Tower Computer Case with Upgraded 2 x USB 3.0](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16811129180) to which I keep an iPod connector connected on the front USB port (with nothing plugged into the other end on startup) as well as a pair of headphones.

That said, what I can do to get the Barracuda drives to be recognized by Windows 8 without having to go into the BIOS every time I start up?

Comment: Power issue perhaps?  If you disconnect one of them to lighten the power load, does the remaining drive(s) work as expected?

Comment: @techie007 Possibly?  But by that logic, neither drive should *ever* appear, no (I know very little about this, please bear with me)?.  What's different about the power going into the BIOS before Windows 8 comes up than not?

Comment: Power is not a steady "always on' thing.  Especially if you've got a failing or just slightly underpowered PSU. Drive spinup eats a lot of power, stopping in the BIOS may give enough time for power to become steady and turn on all the drives.  It's a suggestion of something you can try, unless you've got a spare (larger) PSU and/or motherboard laying around?

Comment: Also, have you tired another OS (like a Linux LiveCD for example) to see if it behaves the same way?

Comment: @techie007 No, not offhand. =)  I'll try unplugging one of the drives and seeing if it shows.  Is it possible that the PSU doesn't have enough power for both drives?  If so, how would I detect *that* case, as I wouldn't be able to tell with certainty if it's the PSU or another reason.

Comment: I had the same idea and I just read the linked documentation. Sadly I can't find a staggered spin-up jumper in the documentation. Just a 4 pin jumperblock, two of which are used to set SATA 1.5GBs mode and one which is undocumented.

Comment: @techie007 RE: Other OS. No, that's not really an option (I don't have a spare drive lying around I could use as another boot drive).

Comment: @Hennes Yeah, I don't think I've ever seen a desktop board that has staggered spin-up options. Unfortunately :(

Comment: @casperOne That's why I suggested a [LiveCD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_CD) :)

Comment: Most of my SCSI and SAS drives have that option. I do not expect the same from all IDE or SATA drives, but a Barracuda has a relative good name, so I hoped the jumper was there.

Comment: @techie007 I'll see if I can make a bootable USB drive, as I opted to not have an optical drive.  Do I run a risk of corrupting the other drives, especially since they have partitions that are merged through Disk Manager if I do this? I also updated the question with the PSU details and everything that could be drawing power.

Comment: @techie007 I've booted the system twice, once with each of the Barracuda's power cord pulled (leaving the other one in) but neither showed up in Windows Explorer.

Comment: @casperOne I have not seen anything about updating the BIOS. Check with the manu to see if there is a BIOS update that can be applied.

Comment: Latest BIOS is dated Jan 10 2013, also there are 2 sata drivers for Win 8, one for Asmedia and one for Marvel. Won't hurt to try em out. http://www.asus.com/Motherboard/P9X79_PRO/#support_Download_36

Comment: I agree with @RockyFord try reinstalling the drivers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [RockyFord's suggestion](https://superuser.com/questions/542487/hard-drives-not-recognized-on-windows-8-unless-entering-bios-first#comment665213_542487), downloading and installing the [latest drivers](http://www.asus.com/Motherboard/P9X79_PRO/#support_Download_36) (version 3305) resolved the issue; the hard drives are visible without going to the BIOS setup.